# How to map doctrine array to elastic search

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch, mapping

I don't know how to map an array from a doctrine entity to elastic search.
Indexation seems working for 1 but not for the second.

Here is my entity :

```
/**
 * @var array $viewers
 * @ORM\Column(name="permission_viewers", type="array", nullable=false)
 */
protected $viewers;
```

My elastic search `config.yml`:

```
ged_document:
  mappings:
    name: { analyzer: default, type: string }
    year: { analyzer: default, type: string }
    author:
    type: "object"
  properties:
    id: {analyzer: default, type: integer}
  category:
    type: "object"
    properties:
    id: {analyzer: default, type: integer}
    name: {analyzer: whitespace, type: string}
  parent:
    type: "object"
    properties:
    id: {analyzer: default, type: integer}
    onlyAuthor: {type: boolean}
    name: {analyzer: whitespace, type: string}
  viewers: {type: 'nested', index: not_analyzed}
```

The error I get when I try to index elastic search :

> [2017-02-08 08:23:29,751][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Saint Anna] [[unadere]] remove_mapping [[ged_document]]
>   [2017-02-08 08:23:29,772][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Saint Anna] [unadere] create_mapping [ged_document]
>   [2017-02-08 08:23:29,865][DEBUG][action.bulk              ] [Saint Anna] [unadere][2] failed to execute bulk item (index) index {[unadere][ged_document][37], source[{"name":"vente1","year":"2000","author":{"id":10004133},"category":{"id":10,"name":"Commande 1","parent":{"id":2,"onlyAuthor":true,"name":"Espace vente","viewers":["ROLE_UNADERE_CHARGE_DE_MISSION"]}},"tags":[],"breadcrumb":"Espace vente -> Commande 1"}]}
>   org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: object mapping [viewers] trying to serialize a value with no field associated with it, current value [ROLE_UNADERE_CHARGE_DE_MISSION]
>     at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.serializeValue(ObjectMapper.java:702)
>     at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.parse(ObjectMapper.java:497)
>     at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.serializeValue(ObjectMapper.java:706)
>     at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.serializeNonDynamicArray(ObjectMapper.java:695)
>     at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.serializeArray(ObjectMapper.java:604)
>     at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.parse(ObjectMapper.java:489)
>     at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.serializeObject(ObjectMapper.java:554)
>     at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.parse(ObjectMapper.java:487)
>     at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.serializeObject(ObjectMapper.java:554)
>     at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.parse(ObjectMapper.java:487)
>     at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:544)
>     at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:493)
>     at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.prepareIndex(IndexShard.java:492)
>     at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.shardIndexOperation(TransportShardBulkAction.java:409)
>     at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportShardBulkAction.java:148)
>     at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$PrimaryPhase.performOnPrimary(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:574)
>     at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$PrimaryPhase$1.doRun(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:440)
>     at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:36)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   [2017-02-08 08:23:29,873][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Saint Anna] [unadere] update_mapping [ged_document] (dynamic)

```
[Elastica\Exception\Bulk\ResponseException]                                                                                                                            
Error in one or more bulk request actions:                                                                                                                             
index: /unadere/ged_document/37 caused MapperParsingException[object mapping [viewers] trying to serialize a value with no field associated with it, current value [ROLE_UNADERE_CHARGE_DE_MISSION]]
```

How it looks like in DB :

Object 1 :

```
a:2{i:1;s:16:"ROLE_UNADERE_ACJ";i:0;s:30:"ROLE_UNADERE_CHARGE_DE_MISSION";}
```

Object 2 :

```
a:1:{i:0;s:30:"ROLE_UNADERE_CHARGE_DE_MISSION";}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `viewers` is simply an array of strings you cannot map it a `nested` type but you can simply declare it as a string.

```
  viewers: {type: string, index: not_analyzed}
```

ES will then seamlessly create an array of string out of it.

Comment: Thanks you for help but i have to add "return array_values($this->viewers);" in the entity's getter because I don t know why but array was inversed (index 1 before index 0) so sometimes it did not work.

Comment: I don't understand what that has to do with the mapping change to `string``?

Comment: Because otherwise i get this:

  Error in one or more bulk request actions:                                                                                                                             
  index: /unadere/ged_document/35 caused MapperParsingException[failed to parse [category.parent.viewers]]; nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[unknown prope  
  rty [1]];

Comment: Can you show how your document looks like in JSON: `print_r(json_encode(your_doc))` ?

Comment: I am not sure about what you asked : 
`code`
  /** @var Document $document */
        $document = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('UnadereBundle:Ged\Document')->find(38);
        print_r(json_encode($document->getCategory()->getParent()->getViewers()));
        die();
`code`
["ROLE_UNADERE_MARKETING"]

Document is an entity with a Category who has a CategoryTop as parent. Viewers are on CategoryTop.

Comment: You should update your question, code in comments is not legible. I just would like to see the JSON document you'd like to index, i.e. the JSON encoded equivalent of your records. The objects you show above are serialized PHP objects.